# Using results of regular expression in a comparison

Tags: regex, perl, match

I'm trying to use the result of pattern match in a comparison operation. Can't seem to get it to work.

The if statement returns false here:

```
if (('6kjkjd' =~ /(\d)/) > 5) {
  print "Why isn't this printing? 6 is greater than 5.";
}
```

As well as here:

```
my $start;
if ((($start) = '6kjkj' =~ /(\d)/) > 5) {
  print "Why isn't this printing? 6 is greater than 5.";
}
```

I've tried removing the parens from the left side of comparison operation but that always results in a true value:

```
my $start;
if (($start) = '6kjkj' =~ /(\d)/ > 7) {
  print "This gets printed even though 6 is not greater than 7.";
}
```

I realize I could break this into two lines like so:

```
my ($start) = '6kjkj' =~ /(\d)/;
if ($start > 5) {
  print "This works as expected.";
}
```

Still, I'm curious to know why the first three code examples don't work as you might expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List versus scalar context:

```
if (('6kjkjd' =~ /(\d)/)[0] > 5) {
    print "Why isn't this printing? 6 is greater than 5.";
}
```

Basically, within the confines of an `if`-condition, you are in scalar context.

When you write:

```
my $start;
if ((($start) = '6kjkj' =~ /(\d)/) > 5)
```

The assignment to `$start` happens, but the list `($start)` has just one element.

If you insist on writing a complicated expression instead of breaking things into pieces, you can take advantage of the comma operator:

```
if ((($start) = '6kjkj' =~ /(\d)/), $start > 5) {
  print "Why isn't this printing? 6 is greater than 5.";
}
```

As Sam Choukri points out in the comments,

```
if (('6kjkj' =~ /(\d)/) and ($1 > 5)) {
```

is safer, and simpler, than both alternatives that first came to my mind.

Comment: Wouldn't `('6kjkj' =~ /(\d)/)[0] > 5` also work? Seems a little easier to digest.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: That would result in `uninitialized value` warning if the match doesn't find any digits.  Here is another alternative that avoids this problem and is still simple: `if ('6kjkj' =~ /(\d)/ && $1 > 5) {...`

Answer (score 2):

That's because operator `=~` in scalar context returns success of an operation.

Lets make `list-context` (by adding `[0]`):

```
if ((('6kjkjd' =~ /(\d)/)[0]) > 5)
{
  print "Why isn't this printing? 6 is greater than 5.";
}
```